# spring boot error page with resource handlers

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, error-handling, spring-boot, static-resource

tl;dr: how to enable spring's ResourceUrlEncodingFilter for spring boot Error pages?

(Question written while using spring boot 1.3.7.RELEASE and Spring Framework/MVC 4.2.4.RELEASE)

Some background: We have a fairly standard spring boot/spring webmvc project using Thymeleaf as the view layer. We have the out-of-the-box spring boot Resource Chain enabled to serve static assets.

Our thymeleaf views have standard url-encoding syntax in them such as `<script th:src="@{/js/some-page.js}"></script>`. This relies on Spring's `org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter` to transform the url into an appropriately-versioned url such as `/v1.6/js/some-page.js`.

Our error handling is done by:

- setting `server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false`
- subclassing spring boot's default `BasicErrorController` to override `public ModelAndView errorHtml(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)`
- relying on our already-configured thymeleaf view resolvers to render our custom error page

The problem is: the ResourceUrlEncodingFilter isn't applying on our error pages. I assume it's a lack of the filter being registered for ERROR dispatched requests, but it's not obvious to me: a) how to customize this in spring boot; and b) why this wasn't done by default.

#### Update 1:

The issue seems to be with a combination of `OncePerRequestFilter` and the ERROR dispatcher. Namely:

- `ResouceUrlEncodingFilter` does not bind to the ERROR dispatcher by default. While overriding this is messy it's not impossible, but doesn't help due to:
- `OncePerRequestFilter` (parent of `ResourceUrlEncodingFilter`) sets an attribute on the Request indicating it's been applied so as to not re-apply. It then wraps the response object. However, when an ERROR is dispatched, the wrapped response is *not* used and the filter does not re-wrap due to the request attribute still being present.

Worse still, the logic for customizing `boolean hasAlreadyFilteredAttribute` is not overridable by request. `OncePerRequestFilter`'s `doFilter()` method is *final*, and `getAlreadyFilteredAttributeName()` (the extension point) does not have access to the current request object to get the dispatcher.

I feel like I must be missing something; it seems impossible to use versioned resources on a 404 page in spring boot.

#### Update 2: A working but messy solution

This is the best I've been able to come up with, which still seems awfully messy:

```
public abstract class OncePerErrorRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected String getAlreadyFilteredAttributeName() {
        return super.getAlreadyFilteredAttributeName() + ".ERROR";
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilterErrorDispatch() {
        return false;
    }

}

public class ErrorPageCapableResourceUrlEncodingFilter extends OncePerErrorRequestFilter {
    // everything in here is a perfect copy-paste of ResourceUrlEncodingFilter since the internal ResourceUrlEncodingResponseWrapper is private
}

// register the error-supporting version if the whitelabel error page has been disabled ... could/should use a dedicated property for this
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class)
@ConditionalOnClass(OncePerErrorRequestFilter.class)
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
@ConditionalOnEnabledResourceChain
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "server.error.whitelabel", name = "enabled", havingValue="false", matchIfMissing = false)
public static class ThymeleafResourceUrlEncodingFilterErrorConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean errorPageResourceUrlEncodingFilterRegistration() {
        FilterRegistrationBean reg = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        reg.setFilter(new ErrorPageCapableResourceUrlEncodingFilter());
        reg.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.ERROR);

        return reg;
    }
}
```

Better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been reported in [spring-projects/spring-boot#7348](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7348) and a fix is on its way.

It seems you've made an extensive analysis of the issue; too bad you didn't report this issue earlier. Next time, please consider raising those on the Spring Boot tracker.

Thanks!

Comment: I meant to. This was supposed to be step 1 of 2: make sure it's a bug, then report. Just forgot the 'then report'... Thanks for the link.